# Handling weird png-8 with ImageIO

Tags: java, awt, javax.imageio, png-8

I'm working on a tool for Android that takes a png as an input, rescale it for several densities and save them in a directory. (Project that can be found here : https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/

In order to open images, I'm using ImageIO's function readImage (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File))

But I've having some trouble with some PNG-8 files, that I shrunk to minimum size thanks to [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com/)

The thing is, if I open this image with ImageIO, it discards the transparency information and that's annoying. (Meaning, when I rescale it, and save it later, the transparency is discarded)

Here is the image I'm talking about: [image: background] and the rescaled output: [image: rescaled background]

If I'm using Toolkit's createImage method (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage(java.lang.String)) instead of ImageIO's method to get the image, it works correctly, but I don't have get the informations such as color model, etc...

Comment: Just skimmed the source code for `com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader`, and from what I can understand, it simply does not fully support the tRNS chunk for RGB PNGs (ie. no transparency)... However, it is available through the `IIOMetadata`, so what you could do, is to read, rescale, then finally write the image back, along with the metadata from the original.

Comment: Hum, it might not work properly, as I then transform images, before writing them...

Comment: Well, I think it might not work because the process is : open the images. If they are RGB, or indexed color, convert them to ARGB. Then do some resizing/modifications. And the write out some png (at the current state of the program, i'm writing out png-24 and not png-8, even if the input is png-8). And tRNS chunk is used in PNG-8, not 24. So using it wouldn't work.

Comment: As you can see from my PoC below, you don't need to convert to RGB to ARGB to maintain transparency for those cases. You *can* use [tRNS with RGB data](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html), that is what your original image uses. Indexed color needs to be handled differently to get the best results (but still possible to get ok results without resorting to ARGB).

Comment: PS: Some of the confusion here might be caused by the fact that your linked image is not PNG-8 (8 bit indexed), but PNG-24 (24 bit RGB) + tRNS. :-)

Comment: Ouch, burn. The first image ? How do you know that for sure ? Do you have a good tool to recommend, that gives you informations about images ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37463/discussion-between-haraldk-and-redwarp)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PoC that does the trick for me:

```
public class TestPNGResampler {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);

        ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);

        try {
            Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input);

            if (!readers.hasNext()) {
                System.err.println("No reader for " + file);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            // Read image and metadata
            ImageReader reader = readers.next();

            reader.setInput(input);
            IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);

            BufferedImage image = reader.read(0);

            // Rescale the image to 22x66 as in OP (replace as you see fit)
            image = new ResampleOp(22, 66, ResampleOp.FILTER_LANCZOS).filter(image, null);

            // Write image with metadata from original image, to maintain tRNS chunk
            ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("PNG").next();
            ImageOutputStream output = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(args[0] + "_mod.png"));
            try {
                writer.setOutput(output);
                writer.write(new IIOImage(image, Collections.<BufferedImage>emptyList(), metadata));
            }
            finally {
                output.close();
            }
        }
        finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. What I'm trying to do ultimatly is : open the image. if it's an indexed color image, convert it to argb, resize it, create a new indexed color map that match the newly created image if the input was indexed, and then save it. For rescaling, I use the following algorithm : https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html (multiple step bilinear, it produces nice result)

Comment: Makes sense. You can find my `ResampleOp` [here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/tree/master/common/common-image/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image) along with an color reducer/quantizer and error diffusion filter. It's quite old code, but it does the job, and you might find it useful. :-)

Comment: And dithering filter too ? Sounds useful !